# How does $\frac{1}{z}-\frac{z}{\sqrt{L^2+z^2}\left(L+\sqrt{L^2+z^2}\right)}$ become $\frac{L}{z\sqrt{L^2+z^2}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I have the following expression involving lengths $z$ and $L$

$$\dfrac{1}{z}-\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{L^2+z^2}\left(L+\sqrt{L^2+z^2}\right)}$$

I 'need' to simplify this to simplify this down to $$\dfrac{L}{z\sqrt{L^2+z^2}}$$

to get the answer in the back of the book (Griffiths' *Introduction to Electrodynamics*), but I'm getting no where. Would anyone mind pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: Multiply right fraction by $(L-\sqrt{L^2+z^2})/(L-\sqrt{L^2+z^2})$

Comment: Got it, thank you very much! @D.Brogan

Comment: Please show what you have tried with your next question. It can help avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with LCM to make both fractions have the same denominator.

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{z}-\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{L^2+z^2}\big(L+\sqrt{L^2+z^2}\big)}
\\
=\dfrac{\sqrt{L^2+z^2}\big(L+\sqrt{L^2+z^2}\big)}{z\sqrt{L^2+z^2}\big(L+\sqrt{L^2+z^2}\big)}
-\dfrac{z^2}
{z\sqrt{zL^2+z^2}\big(L+\sqrt{L^2+z^2}\big)}\\ 
\\
=\dfrac{\sqrt{L^2+z^2}\big(L+\sqrt{L^2+z^2}\big)-z^2}{z\sqrt{L^2+z^2}\big(L+\sqrt{L^2+z^2}\big)}
=\dfrac{L \sqrt{L^2 + z^2} + L^2}
{z \sqrt{L^2 + z^2}
\big(\sqrt{L^2 + z^2} + L\big)}\\
 \\
=\dfrac{\qquad L\quad\space \big(\sqrt{L^2 + z^2} + L\big)}
{z \sqrt{L^2 + z^2}
\big(\sqrt{L^2 + z^2} + L\big)}
=
\dfrac{L}{z \sqrt{L^2 + z^2}}
\end{align*}